# Convert string with XML to datatable, list or something more manageable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Without having to manually parse the file, does `.Net` have something that will easily convert a string with `XML` to an `XmlElement`, `datatable`, `list` or something that's more manageable?

This is the actual string. This string is currently stored in `XmlNode` object (this is `XmlNode.OuterXml`), but I do not know how to convert to something that I can actually use:

```
<ni>
    <nss>20150927</nss>
    <gp>Addon</gp>
    <ns>CounterBlah1</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah2</ns>
    <ns>CounterSales</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah4</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah5</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah6</ns>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>8</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>30</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>90</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
</ni>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does. What exactly you want from the string?

Comment: I want to iterate the string by getting the `<nad>` for each `<nv>`, and then get the 3rd `<r>` in each `<nv>`.

Comment: If that is all you want, my answer will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Linq-to-Xml` you can get your data like this

```
//using System.Xml.Linq;
//using System.Linq;

//xmlStr = your xml string
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var nvs = xDoc.Descendants("nv");
var nads = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("nad").First().Value).ToList();
var thirdRs = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("r").ElementAt(2).Value).ToList();
```

This is what the code generates, for the sample xml

> nads = [ "Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132", "Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433", "Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665" ]
>   thirdRs = [ "8", "30", "90"]

Comment: @rbhatup Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
          string input = "<ni><nss>20150927</nss><gp>Addon</gp><ns>CounterBlah1</ns><ns>CounterBlah2</ns><ns>CounterSales</ns><ns>CounterBlah4</ns><ns>CounterBlah5</ns><ns>CounterBlah6</ns><nv><nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132</nad><r>0</r><r>15</r><r>8</r><r>3</r><r>2</r><r>2</r></nv><nv><nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433</nad><r>0</r><r>15</r><r>30</r><r>3</r><r>2</r><r>2</r></nv><nv><nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665</nad><r>0</r><r>15</r><r>90</r><r>3</r><r>2</r><r>2</r></nv></ni>";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(reader);​
```